# Error in Dompdf. It shows "class Dompdf\Dompdf" has fatal error and does not show output

Tags: dompdf

The following code in dompdf is not working.

```
<?php 
require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$output= file_get_contents('upload.php');
$dompdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($output));
$dompdf->setPaper('A5', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('codexworld',array('Attachment'=>0));
?>
```

I want the upload.php page to convert into pdf format. But, the error keeps on occuring.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please describe what you try to do. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: The upload.php file doesnot convert into pdf file. Error: Fatal Error..

Comment: Still not enough information. At a minimum we would need to know the details of the error.

Comment: On a separate topic, you seem to be using a recent release of dompdf. As of 0.7.0 Dompdf no longer uses the dompdf_config.inc.php file.